# Constrain Camera Corners to a Path

Tags: camera, bezier-curves

I created this model of a racetrack with the curve and array modifier and deleted the curve after I applied the modifiers. Since I've messed around with the model too many times, there's no way I can bring the curve back by simply undoing. So my question is, is there a way I can have the camera always constrain the the edges of a model? Here's a better example:

[image]

I've tried duplicating the track itself and pressing the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and clicking *Curve from Mesh/Text*, but the curve isn't a regular single ongoing bezier line which a camera can follow, but instead a double line (where the edges would be)

The part where there is a bridge with a lot of vertices was not converted into a curve, but instead a bunch of just empty vertices. Here's an example:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what I can do, I appreciate any help! Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: **Thumb rule I** Avoid applying modifiers unless strictly necessary, **Thumb rule II** If you do keep the originals safe in case you need to go back **Thumb rule III** Don't convert curve to mesh or vice versa without keeping the originals safe **Thumb rule IV** Don't erase original curves and generating objects

Comment: I obeyed every rule except II (since I had to cut parts of the track off to make gaps). I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Only workaround I see is select one of the road edgeloops alone, duplicate it in *Edit Mode,* separate into a new object then convert that to a new curve. You can then smooth the curve out by changing the type from *Poly* to *Bezier* but don't expect miracles, there will be information/detail loss.